# Expose public JWK in Go

Tags: go, jwk

I am trying to expose a JWK's endpoint in Go, but it appears the way I am generating the modulus is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Here is how I have generated my keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
```

And the public part:

```
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -out public_key.pub
```

In my Go program here is what I do:

```
var verifyKey *rsa.PublicKey
verifyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("public_key.pub")
verifyKey, err = jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(verifyBytes)

modulus := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString((*verifyKey.N).Bytes())
exponent := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(big.NewInt(int64(verifyKey.E)).Bytes())
```

And here is how the key is exposed:

```
func (s *ExtAuthzServer) ServeHTTP(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    if request.URL.Path == "/.well-known/jwks.json" {
        log.Printf("[HTTP] jwks requested")
        n := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString((*verifyKey.N).Bytes())
        e := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(big.NewInt(int64(verifyKey.E)).Bytes())
        keys := PublicKeysData{
            Keys: []KeyData{KeyData{"RSA", "go-ext-authz", "sig", n, e}},
        }
        response.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        b, _ := json.Marshal(keys)
        _, _ = response.Write([]byte(b))
        return
    }
}
```

with the following struct definition

```
type PublicKeysData struct {
    Keys []KeyData `json:"keys"`
}

type KeyData struct {
    Kty string `json:"kty"`
    Kid string `json:"kid"`
    Use string `json:"use"`
    N   string `json:"n"`
    E   string `json:"e"`
}
```

And here is the output of a curl (I mean a [HTTPie](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/curl-hack-httpie)):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 419
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 16:35:48 GMT

{
    "keys": [
        {
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "go-ext-authz",
            "kty": "RSA",
            "n": "pulIwmeoYdXIOS+vPMURqJsB2IhL3G+OIgMm8I7FqwgeM1Rf12kxycb8VbAVgaN+cMsVfFzxg+oiUqHW4af6dO503bNgZ88DemO/gT9J9Ob4EcmNNohVX28ts6qRmhOtTN0o4xV3cHXiJYL+JTf3U/GhyEK8bJcIgj1X8kNhl7X3gtza2Ft5S8t61ZepdQJdDIdzq7wpw2DTRJ76rvstOvzvLNjfhPhX48aFaw0tSJKw2LmoawHvUviP6tjro7gFUmLX6xolniv/1U/Uas8ZbNFPZBbUs1mjMccNErtUi02VZuHWqGtHL8v+n7rgso9NMd/ljU+BV/dB2KWnO6dD2Q==",
            "use": "sig"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem? What is not working as expected?

Comment: thank you for your interest.
My Go program exposes my public keys on a HTTP interface (for JWT validation).
When I register it on istio I have the following error

**in jwt_authn config has invalid local jwks: Jwks RSA [n] or [e] field is missing or has a parse error**

Comment: ([JWK](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517) is RFC 7517 and [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) is RFC 7519. See also *[What is JWT, JWS, JWE, and JWK? When should we use which token in our business applications?](https://medium.com/@goynikhil/what-is-jwt-jws-jwe-and-jwk-when-we-should-use-which-token-in-our-business-applications-74ae91f7c96b)*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#page-30), you cannot use standard [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding:

> **6.3.1.1.  "n" (Modulus) Parameter**
>
> The "n" (modulus) parameter contains the modulus value for the RSA
> public key.  It is represented as a Base64urlUInt-encoded value.
>
> Note that implementers have found that some cryptographic libraries
> prefix an extra zero-valued octet to the modulus representations they
> return, for instance, returning 257 octets for a 2048-bit key, rather
> than 256.  Implementations using such libraries will need to take
> care to omit the extra octet from the base64url-encoded
> representation.
>
> **6.3.1.2.  "e" (Exponent) Parameter**
>
> The "e" (exponent) parameter contains the exponent value for the RSA
> public key.  It is represented as a Base64urlUInt-encoded value.
>
> For instance, when representing the value 65537, the octet sequence
> to be base64url-encoded MUST consist of the three octets [1, 0, 1];
> the resulting representation for this value is "AQAB".

Go has [urlEncoding](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64#pkg-variables) which can be additionally configured to use padding, if needed.

Reading the specification above, you probably want to use [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) without any padding.

```golang
 base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(...)
```